# Wordpress/Joomla on Shared IP, URL Not Root - Best Development Workflow?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla, ip-address

we have a VPS for new site development, and were planning on using unique IP addresses for each new site/account so that while in development all links, URLs, etc. would be relative to the root (IP address) while in development and not need to change when going live (redirecting domain). But now our host won't allow us to purchase new IP addresses (according to worldwide shortage).

So now all new sites will be located at: http://shared.ip.add.ress/~cpanelaccount/. That means that while in development the sites are not using a root URL as we have been doing.

1. What is the best workflow while in development for relatively complex CMS solutions where we need to be able to confidently setup and test all links, SEF URLs, plugins, components, etc. without worrying about things getting messed up when the domain is switched (site goes live)?
2. Do we need to do some sort of global redirect in the .htaccess file?
3. Any modifications or strategies specific to Wordpress and/or Joomla installs?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to do an install of the latest WP to be sure, but at least with Joomla it is fairly irrelevant if you install in the root or a subdirectory. In the case of Joomla, there is only one change that needs to be made when moving from a subdirectory to the root. You'd need to change .htaccess to reflect the correct installation directory if you have enabled core SEF. Otherwise, there are no changes that need to be made at all. I am pretty sure WP is just as easy to move, but I'd have to look, it's been a while since I moved a WP site.